# Datediff between 2 columns in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datediff

I've got 2 date columns in my table `(start_date, end_date)`.

I've tried `Datediff(day, start_date, end_date)`, but I was prompt with:

> **invalid column name**

---

**How can I calculate the date difference between these 2 columns?**

Comment: Check your column names or show your full query

Comment: Surely the error description is a good enough pointer as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

select DATEDIFF (day,start_date,end_date) from yourtablename;

Answer (score 2):

Should be `Datediff(day, start_date, end_date)`. There is no 's' at the end of the `day`

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: sorry typo. yes i have tried that but it prompt me invalid column name. any ideas how to retrive the column names properly for calculations?

Answer (score 0):

It should be "**day**"

```
Datediff(day, start_date, end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

be certain that your columns are formated correctly to either be a DATE or DATETIME